# Customize ubuntu (change logo and startup app)

Tags: startup

I want to deploy my system on ubuntu 16.04 and 
I need to customize ubuntu:

- I need to change logo on my company's logo.
- I need to show my app after logo page(don't show desktop)

I can change logo with customzing plymouth. 
I can run my app with /etc/init.d/.

It works, but it shows desktop loading and it isn't good for me.

Is there any way to show my app right after loading logo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to use Ubuntu in "kiosk" mode, where it boots straight to one single application.

This tutorial assumes that you want to use Chrome for the app, but you can easily adapt it to use your app instead.

> This tutorial assumes you’re starting with an Ubuntu desktop, all
>   installed with working network and graphics. While we’re in
>   graphical-land, you might as well go and install Chrome.
>
> I have tested this in a clean 14.04 install but be careful. Back up
>   any important data before you commit.
>
> ```
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt install --no-install-recommends openbox pulseaudio
> sudo usermod -a -G audio $USER
>
> sudo install -b -m 755 /dev/stdin /opt/kiosk.sh << EOF
> #!/bin/bash
>
> xset -dpms
> xset s off
> openbox-session &
> start-pulseaudio-x11
>
> while true; do
>     rm -rf ~/.{config,cache}/google-chrome/
>     google-chrome --kiosk --no-first-run  'http://thepcspy.com'
> done
> EOF
>
> sudo install -b -m 644 /dev/stdin /etc/init/kiosk.conf << EOF
> start on (filesystem and stopped udevtrigger)
> stop on runlevel [06]
>
> emits starting-x
> respawn
>
> exec sudo -u $USER startx /etc/X11/Xsession /opt/kiosk.sh --
> EOF
>
> sudo dpkg-reconfigure x11-common  # select Anybody
>
> echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/lightdm.override  # disable desktop
>
> sudo reboot
> ```
>
> This should boot you into a browser looking at my home page (use
>   sudoedit /opt/kiosk.sh to change that), but broadly speaking, we’re
>   done.
>
> If you ever need to get back into the desktop should be able to
>   Control+Alt+F1 to get to a terminal, log in and then run:
>
> `sudo stop kiosk  # if it's running sudo start lightdm` 
>   
> If you run both
>   at the same time (which should be possible but some people seem to be
>   struggling), lightdm will probably start on VT8 (Control+Alt+F8 to
>   switch).

Source: https://thepcspy.com/read/converting-ubuntu-desktop-to-kiosk/